# Access ViewClient values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I've been trying to figure this out all day and it seems my google-fu has failed me. I can't seem to find a way to access the ViewClient values, specifically ViewClient_Machine_Name and ViewClient_MAC_Address.

I was trying to emulate some VB code that uses the `Environ()` function. With `Environ()` you call `Environ("ViewClient_Machine_Name")` and `Environ("ViewClient_MAC_Address")` to get these values. I can't seem to find anything for C#. I found something using Request, but I got out and haven't been able to find it again.

These values can be seen by typing in "set" in the command prompt.

Comment: is this for VMWare...?

Comment: @Natzely, Were you able to find an answer for this?

Comment: @paqogomez Sorry, it took me a little bit to test it out. I've accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values `ViewClient_Machine_Name` and `MAC_Address` are specific to your machine.

They have been set in your environment variables.

To see them in Windows 8, hit windows key, type "Environment variable" and select "Edit Environment variables for your account".  In the system variables window they will be found.

To read them with C#:

```
var machineName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ViewClient_Machine_Name");
```

MSDN to [read environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx)

MSDN to [write environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx).